# Hyper-V IP Not Visible in Server Manager

Tags: windows, hyper-v

I have a Hyper-V VM running **Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise**. For some reason this VM is not displaying its IP address in the Hyper-V Manager:

[image]

The integration servers enabled on this VM are as shown below:

[image]

Other VMs on my machine are correctly displaying their IP (they're running newer OS's than WinServer2008R2). Can someone please help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe if it is an older version of windows server (2012 or lower basically) you need to install the data exchange service for this function to work.

[Link](http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/hyper-v-installing-integration-services/)